# Dynamics GP eConnect: get data (as opposed to create/update)?

Tags: dynamics-gp, econnect

I'm using eConnect to create and update various items in Dynamics GP, but I can't seem to find how to use it to read data from GP.

For example, I'd like to get the Vendor and Account lists from GP. Is there a way to do this from eConnect? Do I have to use SQL?

Answer (score 2):

You don't *have* to use SQL; you can use `eConnectOut` to retrieve data, but the result sets are somewhat limited out of the box.  In the end I found that just dealing with SQL was easier for me because `eConnectOut` doesn't give you access to all of the GP data without manipulation to the **eConnect_Out_Setup** table which is cumbersome at best.

There's a long list of **DOCTYPEs** in the **eConnect_Out_Setup** table for pre-existing `eConnectOut` queries if you're interested.  The **DOCTYPE** you are probably looking for is **Vendor** (which is in the **PM00200** table if you're using SQL).

Here's an example of `eConnectOut` using C#: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff623639.aspx

If you are using XML for eConnect transactions, here's an example of that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<eConnect xmlns:dt="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:datatypes">
    <RQeConnectOutType>
        <eConnectProcessInfo>
            <Outgoing>TRUE</Outgoing>
            <MessageID>Customer</MessageID>
        </eConnectProcessInfo>
            <eConnectOut>
                <DOCTYPE>Customer</DOCTYPE>
                <OUTPUTTYPE>2</OUTPUTTYPE>
                <INDEX1TO>346710</INDEX1TO>
                <INDEX1FROM>346710</INDEX1FROM>
                <FORLOAD>0</FORLOAD>
                <FORLIST>1</FORLIST>
                <ACTION>0</ACTION>
                <ROWCOUNT>0</ROWCOUNT>
                <REMOVE>0</REMOVE>
            </eConnectOut>
        </RQeConnectOutType>
</eConnect>
```

More documentation on `eConnectOut` can be found [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff623993.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

i use gpwebservice for this

use webservice method 
  **wsDynamicsGP.GetVendorList();**

alternatively you can use the below query

**select VendorId,VENDname as VendorName from  PM00200**